# Hid/Hidden vs Hided

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

I'm a bit confused about the usage of the word "Hided".

The [YouGlish](https://youglish.com/pronounce/hided) website shows some examples where the word "Hided" means hid or hidden. While this [WikiDiff](https://wikidiff.com/hidden/hided) page states the following:

> the difference between hided and hidden is that hided is having hide (skin) of a specified kind while hidden is that has been moved out of sight invisible or unapparent.

What is the correct usage of "Hided"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

YouGlish gets a lot of the transcriptions wrong; the first man says "Young people have **hated** every decision", but his accent makes it sound like **hited**.  The speaker in clip #4 is saying **heeded**, not *hided*.  The speaker in clip #6 says **hidden**, but the transcript says *hided* for some reason.  Other speakers are very young children, or are not native speakers of English, and speak incorrectly.

*Hided* is not a valid conjugation of the most common meaning of *to hide* and never means *hid* or *hidden*.  The conjugation of *to hide*, meaning *to conceal*, is simply
**hid**: past tense; "I hid the book"
**hidden**: past participle; "I have hidden the book"

*Hided* can also mean "possessing a hide (skin)" like

> [Dark-hided cattle seem to be more prone to heat stress than light-hided cattle.](https://books.google.com/books?id=tm4IU7DgV7gC&pg=PA195&dq=hided&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjE35v_kqj3AhXZl4kEHXzABz8Q6AF6BAgHEAI)

or the past tense of the verb *to hide* meaning "to give a beating to; to flog".

> [“I hided him good!” Miss Mary yelled. “Good, I tell you! I hided him like he's never been whupped before.”](https://books.google.com/books?id=MM9NDgAAQBAJ&pg=PT68&dq=%22i+hided+him%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjftLbAlKj3AhXHpXIEHS_6DDEQ6AF6BAgIEAI)

Some dialects may use *hided* as the past tense of *to hide* meaning *to conceal*, but it is not standard English.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. As you can see, being a non-native speaker is not easy. :-)

Comment: You're very welcome!  After looking at YouGlish, I am not sure that I would use it.  It looks like a lot of what you find there is either wrong, or requires a lot of context to interpret properly - and the whole problem is that as a learner, you don't have that context!

Answer (score 4):

the difference between hided and hidden is that hided is having hide (skin) of a specified kind while hidden is that has been moved out of sight invisible or unapparent.

RIGHT.

The verb is **hide, hid, hidden.**

**An animal hide** means the skin of a dead animal that has been treated. Not sure I would accept it as a verb. However, most noun in English can be made into verbs, in which case, this would be a regular verb: hide, hided.

Comment: Nice note at the end. Thanks for your help.

Comment: *Hide* as a verb, follows the same pattern as *skin* and *bone*, meaning *remove the hide/skin/bones*.  The linked video contains some appropriate uses of this, such as "a sexualized deer, waiting to be tanned and hided."

Comment: @Juhasz Well, I said what I had to say. It isn't the same pattern. Boned and hided are regular. Skinned is not.

Comment: I meant the same pattern in the semantic sense: skin => remove the skin; bone => remove the bones; hide => remove the hide.

Comment: @Juhasz Right, okay.